# Is there a package for parallel matrix inversion in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, matrix-inverse

is there a package for matrix inversion in R using parallel computation?

Thanks!

---

Hello. I am having trouble installing the HiPLARb package, here is what I did:

Download auto-installer script: http://www.hiplar.org/downloads/HiPLARb.Installer

`./HiPLARb.Installer --with-openblas --no-gpu --prefix=/home/kaiyin/mylib` 
everything went ok, all prerequesite libraries installed succesully, also the patched version of R 2.15.2

Download the package from http://www.hiplar.org/downloads/HiPLARb_0.1.3.tar.gz

Modify the shell PATH to prepend the patched R bin directory.

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--with-lapack= \ 
-L/home/kaiyin/mylib/lib\ -lopenblas \ 
--with-plasma-lib=/home/kaiyin/mylib \ 
--with-magma-lib=/home/kaiyin/mylib" HiPLARb_0.1.3.tar.gz
```

I got the following error:

configure: error: unrecognized option: `-L/home/kaiyin/mylib/lib -lopenblas'

Try `./configure --help' for more information

ERROR: configuration failed for package  HiPLARb

Please help, thanks!

---

Since -lopenblas is not a valid configure option, I removed it and retried:

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--with-lapack=/home/kaiyin/mylib/lib\
--with-plasma-lib=/home/kaiyin/mylib \ 
--with-magma-lib=/home/kaiyin/mylib" ../HiPLARb_0.1.3.tar.gz
```

This time a new error:

```
configure: error: invalid variable name: ` --with-magma-lib'
```

---

3rd try:

```
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="--with-lapack=/home/kaiyin/mylib/lib\
--with-plasma\
--with-magma\ 
--with-plasma-lib=/home/kaiyin/mylib \ 
--with-magma-lib=/home/kaiyin/mylib" ../HiPLARb_0.1.3.tar.gz 

configure: WARNING: you should use --build, --host, --target
configure: WARNING: invalid host type:  
checking "if PLASMA libraries exist"... configure: WARNING: "No PLASMA option given."
configure: WARNING: "No CUDA option given."
configure: WARNING: "No MAGMA option given."
configure: error: Cannot find MAGMA or PLASMA Libraries. Please install MAGMA, PLASMA or both. Please see the install guide for more details.
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, several; but it depends on what you mean by parallel.

If you mean very large scale parallelism, like won't fit on a single machine and you need a cluster to deal with it, then there are the [PBD packages](http://r-pbd.org/). These require packages like MPI and Scalapack t be installed, but they will typically be available on any cluster used for big technical computing already.

If the matrix will fit on a single node and you just want to throw all of your CPUs at it, the [HiPLAR](http://www.hiplar.org/) package can make use of multiple cpus or even GPUs based on the PLASMA or MAGMA libraries (which again need to be installed).

More generally, the [CRAN HPC task view](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) is a useful listing of these sorts of packages.

Answer (score 0):

in order to parallel computation in R there are several packages

give a look of this [PDF](https://www.rmetrics.org/files/Meielisalp2008/Presentations/Theussl1.pdf) : *Getting the most out of your CPUs
Parallel computing strategies in R*

here a website [High-Performance and Parallel Computing with R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html) where are report several packages about parallel computing in R

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26493/discussion-between-gianni-and-dason)