# Moore-Penrose generalized inverse of a large sparse matrix

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse, large-data

I have a square matrix with a few tens of thousands rows and columns with only a few `1` beside tons of `0`, so I use the `Matrix` package to store that in R in an efficient way. The `base::matrix` object cannot handle that amount of cells, as I run out of memory.

My problem is that I need the *inverse* and also the *Moore-Penrose generalized inverse* of such matrices, that I cannot compute at the time being.

**What I have tried:**

- `solve` yields an `Error in LU.dgC(a) : cs_lu(A) failed: near-singular A (or out of memory)` error
- `MASS::ginv` is not compatible with the `Matrix` class
- there is no direct way to convert a sparse `Matrix` to e.g. `bigmemory::big.matrix`, and that latter neither does work with `MASS::ginv` anyway
- if I try to compute the Choleski factorization of the matrix to later call `Matrix::chol2inv` on that, I get the following error message:

  ```
  Error in .local(x, ...) : 
    internal_chm_factor: Cholesky factorization failed
  In addition: Warning message:
  In .local(x, ...) :
    Cholmod warning 'not positive definite' at file ../Cholesky/t_cholmod_rowfac.c, line 431
  ```
- based on a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298134/advice-about-inversion-of-large-sparse-matrices), I also gave a try to the `pbdDMAT` package on a single node, but `pbdDMAT::chol` yielded an `Cholmod error 'out of memory' at file ../Core/cholmod_memory.c, line 147` error message

**Question in a nutshell:** is there any way to compute the inverse and Moore-Penrose generalized inverse of such sparse matrix, beside falling back to using `matrix` class on a computer with tons of RAM?

---

Quick **reproducible example**:

```
library(Matrix)
n <- 1e5
m <- sparseMatrix(1:n, 1:n, x = 1)
m <- do.call(rBind, lapply(1:10, function(i) {
    set.seed(i)
    m[-sample(1:n, n/3), ]
}))
m <- t(m) %*% m
```

Some descriptives (thanks to Gabor Grothendieck):

```
> dim(m)
[1] 100000 100000
> sum(m) / prod(dim(m))
[1] 6.6667e-05
> table(rowSums(m))

    0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
    5    28   320  1622  5721 13563 22779 26011 19574  8676  1701 
> table(colSums(m))

    0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10 
    5    28   320  1622  5721 13563 22779 26011 19574  8676  1701
```

And some error messages:

```
> Matrix::solve(m)
Error in LU.dgC(a) : cs_lu(A) failed: near-singular A (or out of memory)
> base::solve(m)
Error in asMethod(object) : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
> MASS::ginv(m)
Error in MASS::ginv(m) : 'X' must be a numeric or complex matrix
```

The goal of the **bounty** is to find a way to compute the Moore-Penrose generalized inverse of `m` with less than 8Gb of RAM (speed and performance is not important).

Comment: What do you need to do with the inverse once you compute it? http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72616/solving-for-moore-penrose-pseudo-inverse

Comment: Thank you @BenBolker, I try to implement Formula (22) on page 14 at http://www.scribd.com/doc/226039409#page=14 with large matrices. I would also appreciate any help on how I could save that computation, as computing `D_1` and `D^a_2` was extremely quick with `Matrix::sparseMatrix`, but I got stuck with the (pseduo) inverse.

Comment: Scribd says it's a private document ...

Comment: @BenBolker I am terribly sorry for this lame issue, please try again, I've just updated the privacy settings.

Comment: For some reason, your example `m` isn't creating square matricies.

Comment: Thank you @James, I have just fixed the example. The problem was that the number of rows/columns defaulted to the `max` of the generated sample.

Comment: The example is also not reproducible unless `set.seed` is added.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have very few 1's then your matrix will likely have no more than one 1 in any column and in any row in which case the generalized inverse equals the transpose:

```
library(Matrix)
set.seed(123)
n <- 1e5
m <- sparseMatrix(sample(1:n, n/10), sample(1:n, n/10), x = 1, dims = c(n, n))

##############################################################################
# confirm that m has no more than one 1 in each row and column
##############################################################################
table(rowSums(m))  # here 90,000 rows are all zero, 10,000 have a single one
##     0     1 
## 90000 10000 

table(colSums(m))  # here 90,000 cols are all zero, 10,000 have a single one
##     0     1 
## 90000 10000 

##############################################################################
# calculate generalized inverse
##############################################################################
minv <- t(m)

##############################################################################
# check that when multiplied by minv it gives a diagonal matrix of 0's and 1's
##############################################################################
mm <- m %*% minv

table(diag(mm)) # diagonal has 90,000 zeros and 10,000 ones
##     0     1 
## 90000 10000 

diag(mm) <- 0
range(mm) # off diagonals are all zero
## [1] 0 0
```

**REVISED** Improved presentation.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much @G-Grothendieck! Unfortunately `m` has several `1`s in some columns/rows, despite the fact that it's really sparse: `sum(m) / prod(dim(m))` returns `0.0007337982` on my matrix. I try to come up with a better example.

Comment: What is `table(rowSums(m))` and `table(colSums(m))` and `dim(m)`?

Comment: @G-Grothendieck pls find the details at https://gist.github.com/daroczig/9bc956ce8e1cb210234a until I come up with a real minimal reproducible example.

Comment: This seems denser than I thought but you could reduce the problem size like this:  ix <- union(which(rowSums(m) > 0), which(colSums(m) > 0)); minv <- m; minv[ix, ix] <- f(m[ix, ix])` where f is a generalized inverse function.  Seems `ginv` won't work but if you can find another one maybe that will reduce it enough to help.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much, @G-Grothendieck! I will leave the bounty open for a few further days, but I am pretty sure that the offered reputation points will end up on your account. Thanks again!